# Error in xutility when trying to run program C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, websocket

I'm trying to run an example program for a library called aegis, but when I try to compile the program I get the error

```
\vstudio\vide\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xutility(158,56): error C2664: 'asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp,asio::any_io_executor>::basic_stream_socket<_Ty>(ExecutionContext &,int)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'ExecutionContext &'
with
         [
             _Ty=std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context>,
             ExecutionContext=std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context>
         ]
         and
         [
             _Ty=std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context>
         ]
         and
         [
             ExecutionContext=std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context>
         ]
```

I would try to fix it myself but I have no idea where to start. The code in my main file is:

```
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#define _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <aegis.hpp>

int main() {

    aegis::core bot(aegis::create_bot_t().log_level(spdlog::level::trace).token("NzB3Bjk2MjJF1LK0NzYxNzIx.VBi9lN.tj21KhNBMv8_3hzt9ha3LKK9j5fI"));
    AEGIS_TRACE(bot.log, "Bot object created");
    // With min log level set to trace and wsdbg (websocket debug) set to true
    // the bot will dump all websocket messages to console
    bot.wsdbg = true;
    // These callbacks are what are called when websocket events occur
    bot.set_on_message_create([&](aegis::gateway::events::message_create obj)
        {
            std::string content{ obj.msg.get_content() };
            auto& _channel = obj.msg.get_channel();
            // Simple Hi response
            if (content == "~Hi")
            {
                _channel.create_message("Hello back");
            }
        });
    // start the bot
    bot.run();
    // yield thread execution to the library
    bot.yield();
    std::cout << "Press any key to continue...\n";
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the line of code where the error originates:

```
#endif // __cpp_lib_constexpr_dynamic_alloc
    {
        ::new (_Voidify_iter(_STD addressof(_Obj))) _Ty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
    }
```

The messages after the error are:

```
D:\vstudio\vide\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xutility(158,77): message : A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue
 D:\project\asio-master\asio-master\asio\include\asio\basic_stream_socket.hpp(113,3): message : see declaration of 'asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp,asio::any_io_executor>::basic_stream_socket'
 D:\vstudio\vide\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\memory(2021): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Construct_in_place<_Ty,std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context>>(_Ty &,std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context> &&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
         with
         [
             _Ty=asio::ip::tcp::socket
         ]
 D:\vstudio\vide\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\memory(2747): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Ref_count_obj2<_Ty>::_Ref_count_obj2<std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context>>(std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context> &&)' being compiled
         with
         [
             _Ty=asio::ip::tcp::socket
         ]
 D:\vstudio\vide\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\memory(2748): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Ref_count_obj2<_Ty>::_Ref_count_obj2<std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context>>(std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context> &&)' being compiled
         with
         [
             _Ty=asio::ip::tcp::socket
         ]
 D:\project\websocketpp-master\websocketpp-master\websocketpp\transport\asio\security\none.hpp(172): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<websocketpp::transport::asio::basic_socket::connection::socket_type> std::make_shared<asio::ip::tcp::socket,std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context>>(std::reference_wrapper<asio::io_context> &&)' being compiled
```

Comment: That error is not because your program cannot run.  That is a compiler error -- your program hasn't successfully been built yet.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I see, how would I go about fixing the error?

Comment: Look to see where in your code the error originated.  If you are using Visual Studio, the error output will or should eventually point to a line in your code where the error originated from.  But honestly, if you don't know C++, you won't do yourself favors in trying to figure out non-trivial C++ errors.

Comment: These types of errors usually have a lot more context printed before or after. For example in this case it should say what type was trying to be substituted for `_Ty`

Comment: @PeterT Thank you I see what you mean, I've added that to the post.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've posted the line of code from where the error originated.

Comment: looks like there's a missing `std::remove_reference_t<T>` somewhere in there. Having a reference to a reference_wrapper seems wrong. The surrounding messages should also tell you which function that call/instantiation was made in

Comment: @geraldsing34 No, you didn't look hard enough.  Post the code in *your* program where the error originated.  There is a line in the code *you* wrote where the cascading set of errors start.

Comment: @PeterT I see, thank you for explaining. I'm still not quite sure which message/function in the code made the call, I've added all the messages after the error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't write any of it, It's an example from the library that I'm using. I've posted all the errors/messages that appear, and none of them point to my example code.

Comment: this commit https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/commit/c769c9238ad62178f506038178714a1c35aa2769#diff-4f2d1c5e172580e501cd2f4de10a0faffe48c0bb673a6720733bc7d1459da5f4L171 seems to have removed that make_shared there for a reason, update the websocketpp version

Answer (score 0):

You are using incompatible boost asio and websocketpp versions.

This compatibility issue was fixed in websocketpp here: https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/commit/c769c9238ad62178f506038178714a1c35aa2769#diff-4f2d1c5e172580e501cd2f4de10a0faffe48c0bb673a6720733bc7d1459da5f4L171

The easiest thing you can do to resolve this is to update websocketpp.

Comment: That fixed the error but now I have errors from asio 